# How to check the text box value that exist in the database after submit the form

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database

I have this HTML Code in a form, I would like to check whether this value that user input is already exist in the database or not.

```
<tr height="50">
    <td valign="top"><label for="CINumber"><span style="color:red">*</span>CI Name:</label></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="CINumber" name="CINumber"></td>                     
</tr>
```

I have this ``JavaScript function for sumbmit the form values:

```
function submit(){
    var cNumber = document.getElementById("CINumber").value;
     //many form value within this function but I showed this value only cause this value need to check when click submit button.
    $.ajax({
        url: 'PHPMethodCalls_AL.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {'action':'AddNewCI', 'cNumber' : cNumber },
        success: function(data,status) {
            //alert(data);                                                              
            if(status == "success"){                            
                alert("CI Name can be assigned");
                alert("Successfully Register New CI Record.");                              
            } else {
                alert("CI Name is already present!");
                return ;
            }   
        },                              
        error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
        }
    });                                                                         
}
```

And I call the PHPMethod Call in the 'PHPMethodCalls_AL.php' url..

```
if($_POST['action'] == "AddNewCI"){
    $cNumber = $_POST['cNumber'];
    $newCI = AddNewCI($cNumber);
    echo json_encode($newCI );
}
```

After that I call the `PHP` function that connect with the database.

```
function AddNewCI($cNumber){
    global $DB;
    if(!empty($cNumber)){   
        $namequery="SELECT Name from Item where Name='$cNumber'";
        $namecheck=mysql_query($namequery);
        $row=mysql_num_rows($namecheck);

        if($row==0){                     
            echo "success";
            $strSql1 ="INSERT INTO Item (Name)VALUES('$cNumber')";
            $res1 = $DB->Query($strSql1, false, $err_mess.__LINE__);                    
        }
        else {  
            echo "!success";
        }
    }                                                       
}
```

After click submit, I only got the (status == "success") then pop up 2 alert box  even the data is already exist in the database. However, the duplicate value don't save in the database cause I made the UNIQUE for this fields. Please suggest me how should I do to get the the right alert box if the data was exist, show "Alredy exist" if not " show the success alert box"...

Comment: change `echo "success";` to `return "success";` and `echo "!success";` to `return "!success";`

Comment: @B.Desai.. um.. it doesn't work even changed as return :(

Comment: don't use mysql_query , it is deprecated use mysqli_query or PDO.

Comment: change your ajax success condition 'if(data == "success"){                                  }' as you are not assigning/giving status variable in data.

Comment: @GaurangSondagar When I changed,  'if(data == "success"), it only show else condition even the data is not exist in the database but the data is saved into the database but showing wrong alert box .

Comment: first check in your php file that what value you are getting in function return value. if it is success then fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change following code ...

```
                            url: 'PHPMethodCalls_AL.php',
                            type: 'post',
                            data: {'action':'AddNewCI', 'cNumber' : cNumber },

                            success: function(data) {

                            if(data == "success"){                            
                                alert("CI Name can be assigned");
                                alert("Successfully Register New CI Record.");                              
                            }
```

no need to use json_encode , you can directly echo any value if you want.

```
if($_POST['action'] == "AddNewCI"){
$cNumber = $_POST['cNumber'];
$newCI = AddNewCI($cNumber);
echo $newCI;
}
```

change you function return value...

```
function AddNewCI($cNumber){
    global $DB;

        if(!empty($cNumber)){   

            $namequery="SELECT Name from Item where Name='$cNumber'";
            $namecheck=mysql_query($namequery);
            $row=mysql_num_rows($namecheck);
        if($row==0){                     
                $strSql1 ="INSERT INTO Item (Name)VALUES('$cNumber')";
                $res1 = $DB->Query($strSql1, false, $err_mess.__LINE__); 
                return "success";                   
            }
        else
            {   
                 return "error";
            }

        }                                                       
   }
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! it worked... when I change echo($newCI) instead of using json_encode.

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: don't use mysql queries , prefer to use mysqli queries http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php OR PDO http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php. mysql queries are now deprecated in php.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. :) it helps me alot.

Answer (score 0):

Change your success function with this in ajax request :

```
success:fucntion(data){
  if(data=="success"){
    alert("Your success message here.");
  }else{
    alert("Alert message whatever you want.");
  }
},
```

Comment: When I changed,  'if(data == "success"), it only show else condition even the data is not exist in the database but the data is saved into the database but showing wrong alert box .

Answer (score 0):

> **try this one less code and working well**
>       here no need to display error message if you use jquery validation you can simply use "render"   and render function displayed error message like required in jquery 
>         
>          // When the browser is ready...
>         $(function() {
>         // Setup form validation on the #register-form element
>         $("#addfrm").validate({

```
   // Specify the validation rules
    rules: {
      CINumber: {
            required: true,
            remote: {
            url: "PHPMethodCalls_AL.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {
              CINumber: function() {
                return $( "#CINumber" ).val();
              }
            }
          }
        }
    },

    // Specify the validation error messages
    messages: {
        CINumber: {
            required: "Please enter your CINumber",
            remote:"Entered CINumber already exists please enter another one"
       }
    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
});
</script>

 PHPMethodCalls_AL.php
   this file return true when cinumber not exits on database and when it`s return false that means cinumber already exits on database      


<?php
   //add database configuration 
   $CINumber=$_POST['CINumber'];
   $query="SELECT * FROM `table_name` where `CINumber`=$CINumber";
   $result=mysql_query($query);
   $number_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
   if($number_of_rows){
      echo "false";
   }else{
     echo "true";
   }
   die();
   ?>
```